# junit test fails even if expected exception is thrown

Tags: java, exception, testing, junit4

I have this junit test that doesn't work as expected

```
@Test(expected = NoProviderAvailableException.class)
public void testNoProviderAvailableException() throws Exception {

    List<String> nodeSvc = new ArrayList<>();
    nodeSvc.add("addition");

    NodeManifest node = new NodeManifest("localhost", nodeSvc);

    ArithmeticServer arithmeticServer = new ArithmeticServer(managementClient.registerNode(node));
    arithmeticServer.start();       

    OperationDispatcher dispatcher = new OperationDispatcher(managementClient);
    //Thread.sleep(4);

    try {
        dispatcher.executeOperation("subtraction", 1, 2);
    } finally {
        arithmeticServer.stop();
    }
}
```

The test fails with a java.lang.NullPointerException although it should just throw the expected exception. if i uncomment the line

```
//Thread.sleep(4);
```

the test throws the expected exception. Obviously that is not a robust solution to the problem, so i'd like to know what is wrong?

edit: here's the code of OperationDispatcher:

```
public class OperationDispatcher {

    private static Random random = new Random(10);

    public OperationDispatcher(ManagementService.Client managementClient) {
        this.managementClient = managementClient;
    }

    private ManagementService.Client managementClient;
    private ArithmeticService.Client arithmeticClient;  

    public long executeOperation(String opName, int num1, int num2) throws TException, NoProviderAvailableException {

        ServiceProvider provider = null;
        List<ServiceProvider> providers = managementClient.getProvidersForService(opName);

        long result = 0;

        if (providers.isEmpty())
            throw new NoProviderAvailableException();
        else {
            provider = providers.get(random.nextInt(providers.size()));

            TTransport arithmeticTransport = new TSocket(provider.getHostName(), provider.getPort());
            TProtocol arithmeticProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(arithmeticTransport);
            arithmeticClient = new ArithmeticService.Client(arithmeticProtocol);
            arithmeticTransport.open();

            switch(opName) {
            case "addition":
                result = arithmeticClient.add(num1, num2);
                break;
            case "multiplication":
                result = arithmeticClient.multiply(num1, num2);
                break;
            case "subtraction":
                result = arithmeticClient.substract(num1, num2);
                break;
            case "division":
                result = arithmeticClient.divide(num1, num2);
                break;
            }

            arithmeticTransport.close();
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

edit2: here's the stack trace:

> [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on. [INFO] Scanning for
>   projects... [INFO] [INFO] Using the builder
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethrea
>   ded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1 [INFO] [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building Apache Thrift Example 1.0 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources
>   (default-resources) @ thrift-exa mple --- [WARNING] Using platform
>   encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is
>   platform dependent! [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory
>   c:\Users\Jacob\workspace\thrift-examp le\src\main\resources [INFO]
>   [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @
>   thrift-exampl e --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to
>   date [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources
>   (default-testResources) @ th rift-example --- [WARNING] Using platform
>   encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is
>   platform dependent! [INFO] Copying 2 resources [INFO] [INFO] ---
>   maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ thrif
>   t-example --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
>   [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @
>   thrift-example ---
>
> [INFO] Surefire report directory:
>   c:\Users\Jacob\workspace\thrift-example\target \surefire-reports
>
> -------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
>   ------------------------------------------------------- Running it.uniud.atta.thrift.ManagementServiceTest Starting management server
>   on port: 7911...
>
> listening for requests...
>
> Shutting down management server on port: 7911
>
> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.278
>   sec Running it.uniud.atta.thrift.OperationDispatcherTest Tests run: 2,
>   Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.921 sec <<< FA
>   ILURE!
>   testNoProviderAvailableException(it.uniud.atta.thrift.OperationDispatcherTest)
>   Time elapsed: 0.205 sec  <<< ERROR! java.lang.Exception: Unexpected
>   exception, expected but was
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(Expect
>   Exception.java:31)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.
>   java:28)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.ja
>   va:30)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
>           at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRun
>   ner.java:68)
>           at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRun
>   ner.java:47)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provide
>   r.java:252)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4
>   Provider.java:141)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider
>   .java:112)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(
>   ReflectionUtils.java:189)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke
>   (ProviderFactory.java:165)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(Provi
>   derFactory.java:85)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(Fork
>   edBooter.java:115)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:
>   75) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at it.uniud.atta.thrift.impl.ArithmeticServer.stop(ArithmeticServer.java
>   :37)
>           at it.uniud.atta.thrift.OperationDispatcherTest.testNoProviderAvailableE
>   xception(OperationDispatcherTest.java:109)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(Framework
>   Method.java:45)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCal
>   lable.java:15)
>           at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMe
>   thod.java:42)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMet
>   hod.java:20)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(Expect
>   Exception.java:22)
>           ... 23 more
>
> Results :
>
> Tests in error:
>   testNoProviderAvailableException(it.uniud.atta.thrift.OperationDispatcherTest)
>   : Unexpected exception,
>   expected but
>   was
>
> Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
>
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 2.183 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2014-06-16T18:48:20+01:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
>   12.4:test (default-test) on project thrift-example: There are test failures. [ERROR] [ERROR] Please refer to
>   c:\Users\Jacob\workspace\thrift-example\target\surefire- reports for
>   the individual test results. [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal o
>   rg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test
>   (default-test) on proj ect thrift-example: There are test failures.
>
> Please refer to
>   c:\Users\Jacob\workspace\thrift-example\target\surefire-reports for
>   the individual test results.
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
>   .java:212)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
>   .java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
>   .java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
>   ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
>   ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThre
>   adedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
>   eStarter.java:116)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
>   java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
>   sorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
>   cher.java:289)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
>   a:229)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
>   uncher.java:415)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
>   356) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There
>   are test failures .
>
> Please refer to
>   c:\Users\Jacob\workspace\thrift-example\target\surefire-reports for
>   the individual test results.
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(Suref
>   ireHelper.java:83)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.writeSummary(Surefire
>   Plugin.java:176)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(Surefir
>   ePlugin.java:150)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPre
>   conditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:650)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(Abstrac
>   tSurefireMojo.java:586)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
>   BuildPluginManager.java:133)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
>   .java:208)
>           ... 19 more

Comment: Well, how does `Thread.sleep` affect your program?

Comment: it adds a delay just after a management server is put up and before any request to the method executeOperaton is made.

Comment: I think that only you yourself can answer this question. You are calling method `executeOperatioon()` and expecting that it will throw exception. Examine your code and try to understand why it does not work as expected unless your add some delay. Is it some kind of asynchhropnous initialization there? If you want us to help you please send the NPE stack trace and code of your `OperationDispatcher`

Comment: Added code for OperationDispatcher class. I forgot to mention that only maven returns the wrong exception. Eclipse runs the test as expected

Comment: You still haven't included the stack trace of the NPE though. Basically you've got a race condition somewhere, and you've got information which will help you find out where - but you haven't provided it.

Comment: Does `ArithmeticServer.start` block until it's ready to receive requests? If that's basically asynchronous, that could well be the issue.

Comment: i'm sorry, how can I provide the NPE stack trace from github?

Comment: Ok I've added the NPE.